# How to get real client IP on gRPC Java server side using Nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: java, nginx, reverse-proxy, grpc

I use grpc-java as server backend and Nginx as load balancer between server and client, now I can get request Metadata like this

```
Metadata(content-type=application/grpc,user-agent=grpc-java-netty/1.12.0,grpc-accept-encoding=gzip,grpc-trace-bin=)
```

and client IP by Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR like this

```
{remote-addr=/10.10.10.202:54031}
```

Obviously it's the local IP of Nginx node. I already set X-Real-IP and X-Forwarded-For in nginx.conf

```
...
server  {
    listen       50010 http2;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
...
```

these 2 keys should be present in request Metadata.  Could anyone help me out? The version of gRPC is 1.12 and version of nginx is 1.15.2 on CentOS 7.4

Comment: grpc_set_header?

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can access all the headers by looking at the Metadata for the ServerCall.  Metadata and headers are the same thing.  Normally, the StreamObservers don't expose this to you, as most users don't care about headers.

In your case, you can use a `ServerInterceptor` to access the Metadata. The correct way to expose this is by pulling the correct header out of the Metadata and put it into the `Context`.  The context is scoped to the ServerCall and can be accessed outside of the interceptor.  In your server handler, you can call `Context.current()` and get the value you using the `Context.Key` you used to put the header in the context.

Answer (score 1):

1. config "grpc_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;"
   [nginx for grpc: grpc_set_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_grpc_module.html#grpc_set_header)

```sh
server {
    listen  9099  http2;
    access_log    /var/log/nginx/access-grpc.log;
    location / {
        grpc_pass grpc://127.0.0.1:9091;
        grpc_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

2. get metadata from context in gRPC server side

   my golang code:

```golang
md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)
...
md.Get("x-real-ip")
...
```

Comment: 1. config "grpc_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;"
2. get metadata from context in gRPC server side

my golang code:

```
md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)
...
md.Get("x-real-ip")
...
```